# jdbcRealm stopped working after Glassfish reboot

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3, jdbcrealm

After many attempts I managed to configure jdbcRealm with MySQL. Unfortunately, some time later a database error occurred (too many connection per user) and I was forced to reboot Glassfish 3.1.1

After the reboot I can no longer use basic authentication based on my jdbcRealm, although I can successfully ping the database.

I get following error:

```
[#|2012-08-24T15:17:53.472+0200|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login|_ThreadID=127;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver;MethodName=doPasswordLogin;|Logging in user [myUser] into realm: ShibUserPassAuth using JAAS module: jdbcRealm|#]

    [#|2012-08-24T15:17:53.478+0200|FINEST|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login|_ThreadID=127;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver;MethodName=doPasswordLogin;|doPasswordLogin fails
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for jdbcRealm
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:273)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:382)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:240)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:153)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:512)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:453)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:168)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1326)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]

[#|2012-08-24T15:17:53.479+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security|_ThreadID=127;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: No LoginModules configured for jdbcRealm|#]

[#|2012-08-24T15:17:53.480+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security|_ThreadID=127;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: No LoginModules configured for jdbcRealm
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:394)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:240)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:153)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:512)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:453)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:168)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1326)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for jdbcRealm
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:273)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:382)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:381)
    ... 29 more
```

What could possibly have changed during the reboot? I read all Stack articles related to jdbcRealm, and I believe that I have proper configuration of all jdbc connector, secure Realm and data tables. It was working before the reboot.

Update 1
@Nick Wilson

my {GLASS_HOME}/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf

```
/*
 * DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS HEADER.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2004-2010 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * The contents of this file are subject to the terms of either the GNU
 * General Public License Version 2 only ("GPL") or the Common Development
 * and Distribution License("CDDL") (collectively, the "License").  You
 * may not use this file except in compliance with the License.  You can
 * obtain a copy of the License at
 * https://glassfish.dev.java.net/public/CDDL+GPL_1_1.html
 * or packager/legal/LICENSE.txt.  See the License for the specific
 * language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
 *
 * When distributing the software, include this License Header Notice in each
 * file and include the License file at packager/legal/LICENSE.txt.
 *
 * GPL Classpath Exception:
 * Oracle designates this particular file as subject to the "Classpath"
 * exception as provided by Oracle in the GPL Version 2 section of the License
 * file that accompanied this code.
 *
 * Modifications:
 * If applicable, add the following below the License Header, with the fields
 * enclosed by brackets [] replaced by your own identifying information:
 * "Portions Copyright [year] [name of copyright owner]"
 *
 * Contributor(s):
 * If you wish your version of this file to be governed by only the CDDL or
 * only the GPL Version 2, indicate your decision by adding "[Contributor]
 * elects to include this software in this distribution under the [CDDL or GPL
 * Version 2] license."  If you don't indicate a single choice of license, a
 * recipient has the option to distribute your version of this file under
 * either the CDDL, the GPL Version 2 or to extend the choice of license to
 * its licensees as provided above.  However, if you add GPL Version 2 code
 * and therefore, elected the GPL Version 2 license, then the option applies
 * only if the new code is made subject to such option by the copyright
 * holder.
 */

fileRealm {
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.FileLoginModule required;
};

ldapRealm {
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LDAPLoginModule required;
};

solarisRealm {
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.SolarisLoginModule required;
};

jdbcRealm {
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule required;
};

jdbcDigestRealm {
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.JDBCDigestLoginModule required;
};
pamRealm {
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PamLoginModule required;
};
```

Update 2

I found out, that I didn't mention that the basic authentication is being activated. User receive pop-up login window, as it was before, but now It can't be authenticated and receive stacktrace listed above, with every login attempt.

Comment: Modifications on the Realm settings may take place on GlassFish restart. Consequently, it's possible that you have modified them some time ago, and the new settings have been committed only now.

Comment: The "No LoginModules Configured" error can be related to the domains "login.conf" file. You should find this in the domain/config folder. Is the file still there and does it contain an entry for jdbcRealm?

Comment: @perissf
Unfortunately I double checked the configuration, and "saved" it from admin console. Still doesn't working.

Comment: @Nick Wilson
In domains/domain1/config there is login.config file a inside there is this line:

jdbcRealm { com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule required; };

Any other hints?

Comment: Problem still unsolved. Any help or suggestion will be gladly welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was resolved, some time ago, in [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284583/all-glassfish-login-modules-stopped-working-after-container-reboot)

One of a third party applications was loading it's own login.conf file, which was loaded after deployment and glassfish reboot, consequently destroying previous JAAS configuration